# Deserialized an object into a DataTable

Tags: json, vb.net, datatable

I have a `JSON` response like this:

```
{  "cod": "OK", 
"list": [
    {  "date": "31\/10\/2018", "count": "109",  "name": "PAUL"  },
    {  "date": "30\/09\/2018", "count": "103",  "name": "LUKE"  }
]}
```

I use:

```
 Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer
 Dim Response = jss.Deserialize(Of Object)(strResponse)
 Dim Cod = Response("cod")
```

Then:

```
Dim Lista_documents = Response("list")
```

And I have an object with the list of documents.
How can I populate a new `DataTable`?

Comment: You didn't explain how you want to populate it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any methods that will do it automatically, so probably with a Loop.

```
Dim table As New DataTable
table.Columns.Add("date", GetType(Date))
table.Columns.Add("count", GetType(Integer))
table.Columns.Add("name", GetType(String))

For Each Li In Lista_documents
    table.Rows.Add(Li("date"), Li("count"), Li("name"))
Next
```

Adjust depending on how your Lista_documents is structured